# Hazelcast Rest API returns no content

Tags: java, rest, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Running hazelcast (3.4) on linux (rh).
I've created MAP in one instance, added couple records:

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<String,Event> map = hz.getMap("EVENTS");
```

I'm able to read map using java client, HazelcastClient, but not
able to see anything when hitting REST interface with curl or browser:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/EVENTS/
```

in fact browser shows response code 204 - no content

Answer (score 0):

looks like it has limited REST interface.
I would expect to receive all elements using url above.
I found that only this works to read data:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/EVENTS/some-key-value
```